# Output not logged to file in Windows shell

Tags: windows, logging, vbscript

When running

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a c:\Temp\Test.zip c:\Intel\* >c:\Temp\Test.log
```

from the command prompt on Win10, everything works as it is supposed to work: the files are compressed in the ZIP archive and the output of 7-Zip is written to the log file.

Transferring this line to the following VBScript sample code

```vb
Dim oWsh: Set oWsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim s7zip: s7zip = """C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"" a c:\Temp\Test.zip c:\Intel\* >c:\Temp\Test.log"
oWsh.Run s7zip
```

results again in the files being compressed in the ZIP archive but the output will not be written to the log file since no log file will be written at all. I guess this behaviour has something to do with "StdOut not being StdOut" when a command is run in the Windows shell, but I haven't found any explanation or solution for the problem. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection operator (`>`) is a CMD-builtin feature. You need to run your command within CMD for it to work.

```vb
s7zip = "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"" a ..."
oWsh.Run s7zip, 0, True
```